# How to create a simple transformation function on lists using short form of ReplaceAll?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, replacement, pattern-matching, symbols

I can easily do this with `Map` so the real goal of this exercise is to get a better grip on using transformation rules. Please help with this. The outputs should be of the form `{{symbol,head},...}` with all in alphabetical order. Thank you.

```
Quiet@Remove@"Global`*";
SetAttributes[toSymbol, {Orderless, Listable}]
SymbolQ[_Symbol] := True;
SymbolQ[_] := False;
seq = Sequence[z, y, x];
str = {"c", "b", "a"};
toSymbol[args__] := 
  Flatten@{args} /. {# -> {Symbol@(ToString #), Head@#}} &;
toSymbol[str]
toSymbol[seq]
toSymbol[str, seq]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit tricky because you need to work with levels and "ReplaceAll" can not take a level. Instead you may use "Replace" with a level specification of {1}:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
seq = Sequence[z, y, x];
str = {"c", "b", "a"}; toSymbol[args__] :=
 Replace[Flatten[{args}], x_ :> {Head[x], x}, {1}];
toSymbol[str]
toSymbol[seq]
toSymbol[str, seq]
```

[image]

Comment: sorry about late response. this really helps. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
seq = Sequence[z, y, x];

str = {"c", "b", "a"};
```

Using `Comap` (new in 14.0}

```
Comap[{Head, Identity}] /@ Flatten[{str}]
```

{{String, "c"}, {String, "b"}, {String, "a"}}

```
Comap[{Head, Identity}] /@ Flatten[{str, seq}]
```

{{String, "c"}, {String, "b"}, {String, "a"}, {Symbol, z}, {Symbol,
y}, {Symbol, x}}

Using `Query`

```
Query[All, {Head, Identity}] @ Flatten[{str, seq}]
```

{{String, "c"}, {String, "b"}, {String, "a"}, {Symbol, z}, {Symbol,
y}, {Symbol, x}}